# MySQL Cursor and Prepare Statement - What is Wrong

Tags: mysql, cursor, execute

I am trying to create a procedure in MySQL that uses a cursor and an execute. I would like to introspect the schema and update all tables that have a version column, setting the version to  0. I think I am missing a loop (looking for help here), but I am also getting an error with my dynamic SQL.  Any ideas?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE update_version_number(schemaName int)

BEGIN

    DECLARE the_table_name VARCHAR(200);

    DECLARE version_cursor CURSOR 

    FOR 

    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = "myschema" AND COLUMN_NAME = "version" AND TABLE_NAME <> "db_info";



    OPEN version_cursor;

    FETCH version_cursor into the_table_name;



    PREPARE run_version_update From 'UPDATE ? SET version = 0';

    SET @a = the_table_name;

    EXECUTE run_version_update USING @a;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE run_version_update;

    CLOSE version_cursor;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer an issue. I changed how I approached the problem.